# Alternate to recursive for-loop in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, recursion, text

I am relatively new to R.

I have a dataframe `test` that looks like this (only 1 variable `X1` of pure text, but can have up to 20 million rows):

```
DP  - 2017 Jan 01
TI  - Case Report of Severe Antithrombin Deficiency During Extracorporeal Membrane
      Oxygenation and Therapeutic Plasma Exchange for Double Lung Transplantation.
PG  - 11-13
LID - 10.1213/XAA.0000000000000412 [doi]
AB  - Acquired antithrombin (AT) deficiency is not uncommon in cardiothoracic surgery
      because of heparin exposure and dilutional or consumptive losses. We report a
      case of acquired AT deficiency and resultant multiple deep vein thrombosis in a
      patient with pulmonary fibrosis on veno-venous extracorporeal membrane
AD  - From the Departments of *Anesthesiology and daggerCardiothoracic Surgery,
      University of Maryland, Baltimore, Maryland.
JT  - Saudi journal of kidney diseases and transplantation : an official publication of
      the Saudi Center for Organ Transplantation, Saudi Arabia
JID - 9436968
```

I want to recreate the "labels" for the lines that have none (aka have 3 spaces in the beginning) by using the label that precede it. However, I only need to recreate labels for `TI` and `JT` since those will be the only rows I need to extract eventually.

So basically, my resulting dataframe should look like:

```
DP  - 2017 Jan 01
TI  - Case Report of Severe Antithrombin Deficiency During Extracorporeal Membrane
TI  - Oxygenation and Therapeutic Plasma Exchange for Double Lung Transplantation.
PG  - 11-13
LID - 10.1213/XAA.0000000000000412 [doi]
AB  - Acquired antithrombin (AT) deficiency is not uncommon in cardiothoracic surgery
      because of heparin exposure and dilutional or consumptive losses. We report a
      case of acquired AT deficiency and resultant multiple deep vein thrombosis in a
      patient with pulmonary fibrosis on veno-venous extracorporeal membrane
AD  - From the Departments of *Anesthesiology and daggerCardiothoracic Surgery,
      University of Maryland, Baltimore, Maryland.
JT  - Saudi journal of kidney diseases and transplantation : an official publication of
JT  - the Saudi Center for Organ Transplantation, Saudi Arabia
JID - 9436968
```

There are 3 spaces that precede a line without a "label," so this is what my current code is:

```
for (n in 1:nrow(test))
{
  if (substr(test$X1[n], 1, 3) == "   " && (substr(test$X1[n-1], 1, 2) == "TI" || substr(test$X1[n-1], 1, 2) == "JT"))
  {
    if (n > 1)
    {
      subs <- substr(test$X1[[n-1]], 1, 6)
    }
    subs <- substr(test$X1[[n-1]], 1, 6)
    test$X1[n] <- sub("      ", subs, test$X1[n])
  }
}
```

My current solution works but takes forever to run on text that spans over 20 million rows. Please advise, since I will need to run this script on multiple large files.

Thanks.

Comment: First Q: What excludes `AB` and `AD` from the operation? Second Q: Do you need the data in the same order after operation? `dput(head(df,8))` would be helpful here

Comment: I will eventually reshape the data so that `TI` and `JT` will be variable names. I do not need `AB` and `AD` so it's not necessary to perform it on them. And yes, in the same order too.

Comment: So I extracted random rows from a file, so it won't match up at all, but here is what that code outputs:  `structure(list(X1 = c("STAT- MEDLINE", "IP  - 23", "JT  - The New England journal of medicine", 
"CIN - N Engl J Med. 2016 Dec 8;375(23 ):2286-2289. PMID: 27959676", 
"CIN - N Engl J Med. ;376(7):e11. PMID: 28207208", "CIN - N Engl J Med. ;376(7):e11. PMID: 28207209", 
"CIN - N Engl J Med. 2017 Feb 16;376(7):e11. PMID: 28199803", 
"DA  - 20161213")), .Names = "X1", row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: Surprisingly the `for` loop works quite well. I tried a `dplyr`, `map_df`, and `lapply` solution but they were all slower on average in `microbenchmarking`. You should consider parallelization next...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I rewrote your function a little bit:

```
yourFunction <- function(test) {
  for (n in 2:nrow(test)) {
    if (substr(test$X1[n], 1, 3) == "   " &&
        (substr(test$X1[n - 1], 1, 2) == "TI" ||
         substr(test$X1[n - 1], 1, 2) == "JT")) {
      subs <- substr(test$X1[[n - 1]], 1, 6)
      test$X1[n] <- sub("      ", subs, test$X1[n])
    }
  }
  test
}
```

2) Lets create small data set to see how our both functions work:

```
# small test dataset:
require(data.table)

variants <-
  c("TI  - text", "      text2", "AD  - text3", "JT  - text4")
n <- 10
set.seed(26)
dt <- data.table(X1 = sample(variants, size = n, replace = T))
dt
             X1
 1:  TI  - text
 2:       text2
 3: JT  - text4
 4: JT  - text4
 5:       text2
 6:       text2
 7: JT  - text4
 8: AD  - text3
 9:       text2
10: AD  - text3
```

3) results for yourFunction:

```
yourFunction(dt)
             X1
 1:  TI  - text
 2: TI  - text2
 3: JT  - text4
 4: JT  - text4
 5: JT  - text2
 6: JT  - text2
 7: JT  - text4
 8: AD  - text3
 9:       text2
10: AD  - text3
```

4) I wrote this function using `zoo`, `data.table` and `stringi` <s>(probably you could do just fine without last two packages)</s>

```
myFunction1 <- function(dt) {
  require(zoo)
  require(stringi)
  require(data.table)
  d <- copy(dt)
  d[, v6 := substr(X1, 1, 6)]
  # d[, v3 := substr(v6, 1, 3)]
  # d[, emty := ifelse(v3 == "   ", T, F)]
  d[v6 == "      ", v6 := NA]
  d[, v6 := na.locf(v6, na.rm = F)]
  d[is.na(v6), v6 := "      "]
  stri_sub(d$X1, 1, 6) <- d$v6
  d[, "X1", with = F]
}
```

5) compere results:

```
r1 <- yourFunction(dt)
r2 <- myFunction1(dt)
all.equal(r1, r2)
[1] "Column 'X1': 1 string mismatch"

r2
             X1
 1:  TI  - text
 2: TI  - text2
 3: JT  - text4
 4: JT  - text4
 5: JT  - text2
 6: JT  - text2
 7: JT  - text4
 8: AD  - text3
 9: AD  - text2
10: AD  - text3
```

Results are not identical, i recreated also labels you did not want/need. If you need them removed, then you could find some way, but this approach is much faster.

6) Benchmarks: (your function is faster when n is very small)

```
# when n = 10
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(myFunction1(dt),
          yourFunction(dt), replications = 100,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"))
# test replications elapsed relative
# 1  myFunction1(dt)          100    0.21    2.333
# 2 yourFunction(dt)          100    0.09    1.000

# when 1k / with 10 replications
n <-  1 * 1000
set.seed(231)
test <- sample(variants, size = n, replace = T)
dt <- data.table(X1 = test)
benchmark(myFunction1(dt),
          yourFunction(dt), replications = 10,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"))
# test replications elapsed relative
# 1  myFunction1(dt)           10    0.03    1.000
# 2 yourFunction(dt)           10    0.52   17.333

# when 50k
n <-  50 * 1000
set.seed(231)
test <- sample(variants, size = n, replace = T)
dt <- data.table(X1 = test)
dt
benchmark(myFunction1(dt),
          yourFunction(dt), replications = 1,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"))
# test replications elapsed relative
# 1  myFunction1(dt)            1    0.01        1
# 2 yourFunction(dt)            1    7.09      709


# time for 20 mil rows:
n <-  20e6
set.seed(231)
test <- sample(variants, size = n, replace = T)
dt <- data.table(X1 = test)
dt
system.time(myFunction1(dt))
# user  system elapsed 
# 6.23    0.78    7.04
```

Comment: Holy crap! that was surprisingly fast! within seconds, whereas earlier my R would continuously abort after 30+ mins of running...thank you so, so, so much!!!